# SQL join with ordering results by date and PK

Tags: sql

Ok, I have mostly dealt with fairly simple SQL and, in fact, my current problem seems like it should be simple too but I haven't been able to come up with the right search terms to find a solution. I'm joining two tables with a one to many relationship. I want to sort by a date field in the 2nd table while grouping the results by the PK.

```
MAIN
--
MAINID, ACTION, DIVISION
000001, HRREC,  I
000002, AUDIT,  IV
000003, TRAVEL, II

SECONDARY
--
MAINID, AUTHUSER, LOGINDATE,  COMMENTS
000002, Fred,     01/02/2012, Needs work
000001, Smitty,   01/05/2012, making brisk progress
000003, Fred,     03/10/2012, blah blah
000002, Jimmy,    02/15/2011, something
000001, Bill,     01/01/2012, neener neener
000002, Saul,     12/13/2011, no action

DESIRED OUTPUT
--
MAINID, ACTION, DIVISION, AUTHUSER, LOGINDATE, COMMENTS
000003, TRAVEL, II,       Fred,     03/10/2012, blah blah
000001, HRREC,  I,        Smitty,   01/05/2012, making brisk progress
000001, HRREC,  I,        Bill,     01/01/2012, neener neener
000002, AUDIT,  IV,       Fred,     01/02/2012, Needs work
000002, AUDIT,  IV,       Saul,     12/13/2011, no action
000002, AUDIT,  IV,       Jimmy,    02/15/2011, something

The basic join I'd like to order
--
SELECT MAIN.MAINID,MAIN.DIVISION,MAIN.ACTION,SECONDARY.AUTHUSER,SECONDARY.LOGINDATE,SECONDARY.COMMENTS 
FROM MAIN
LEFT JOIN SECONDARY ON MAIN.MAINID=SECONDARY.MAINID;
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not clear what you mean by "grouping the results by the PK"; if the dates have to be sorted for each group of MAINID which MAINID shold be the first? Maybe the MAINID are sorted by the MAX(LOGINDATE)?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to order by LOGINDATE inside groups made by MAINID with groups sorted by MAX(LOGINDATE) you sholud do this:

```
SELECT 
    M.MAINID,
    M.DIVISION,
    M.ACTION,
    S.AUTHUSER,
    S.LOGINDATE,
    S.COMMENTS 
FROM MAIN M LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT 
          MAINID,
          MAX(LOGINDATE) MAXDATE
      FROM SECONDARY
      GROUP BY
          MAINID
     ) Q  
          ON M.MAINID=Q.MAINID
       LEFT JOIN SECONDARY S
          ON M.MAINID=S.MAINID
ORDER BY
    MAXDATE, LOGINDATE;
```

Comment: +1 : Although I'd change it slightly, as there is no need for the join inside the sub-query.  `main LEFT JOIN secondary LEFT JOIN (SELECT mainid, MAX(logindate) FROM secondary GROUP BY mainid)`...